# How to hide an AJAX loading image when visiting link to root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some AJAX loading in my app, and I thought it would be nice to have a loading icon, since there's a little delay. I grabbed some code from http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit. The loading and hiding works fine, except that I have a logo in the header, which is a link to the root:

```
<%= link_to "#{app_name}", root_url, id: "logo" %>
```

Clicking the link takes you to the root, but the loading icon is visible. But if you reload the page, the icon is hidden, as desired. So there's something different about clicking the link.

The view:

```
<div class="spinner">
```

The CSS does not set the hidden attribute. If I set it, the spinner is always hidden.

The jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 // hide spinner
  $(".spinner").hide();


  // show spinner on AJAX start
  $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $(".spinner").show();
  });

  // hide spinner on AJAX stop
  $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $(".spinner").hide();
  });
```

});

I tried adding an onclick even to the logo. That fires first, then the page loads with the spinner visible. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: How about using: 

    `<div class="spinner" style="display:none;">`

And removing: 

     `// hide spinner
      $(".spinner").hide();`

Instead of initialize it with javascript to hide the element, just hide it with css to start with. 

Could you tell me what's happening now?

Comment: Do you using Turbolinks?

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick. I just wasn't familiar with the jQuery. First I had to modify the spinner CSS to set display:none, instead of display:inline-block. I commented out the hide function, as you suggested. To show it, instead of using show, I used $(".spinner").css("display","inline-block");

Comment: Nice find, I've bookmarked this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Terry, this is an accompaniment to the comment which helped you.

There are several things to fix:

---

1. **You should keep your CSS *hidden***, using JQuery to make it *visible*.

You're currently *hiding* your `spinner` on DOM load with JQuery.

Although this will work, it adds unnecessary overhead to your application. Instead, you'll be much better to *show* the `spinner` when Ajax runs:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
.spinner {
   display: none; /* Use this instead of inline styles */
}
```

---

2. You should **bind your spinner to on-page elements**

You're currently binding the `spinner` to `ajaxStart` & `ajaxStop`. These are *global* functions, fired EVERY time Ajax runs.

This may work in a simple application, is bad practice in a more complicated system.

I would do the following:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
spinner = function(){
   $(".spinner").toggle();
}

$(document).on("ajax:beforeSend", function(){
   spinner();
}).on("ajax:complete", function(){
   spinner();
});

$(document).on("click", ".element", function(){
    spinner();
    $.ajax({
      ...
});
```

This uses the [`ajax:beforeSend`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) event handler from Rails UJS (every time you call `remote: true`, this will fire).

It also allows you to use the `spinner` function for any other event/element in your app.